# intermittent issue with php DateTime->diff

Tags: php, datetime

for the most part, my code is working correctly, it is just to give a summary of how long ago something happened.  Basically what's happening is, it will sometimes output "1 day ago" when it should not.  usually this happens a couple hours after something is submitted, and then it will end up reverting back to like "x hours ago" before 24 hours have lapsed.  The datetime formats are matching, this is my current output (its actually working right now) but sometimes it randomly shows 1 day when one day hasn't lapsed:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2021-06-19 02:23:45.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2021-06-18 04:26:31.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
Array
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 21
    [i] => 57
    [s] => 14
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
```

```
<?php

function TimeAgo($RawDate) {
    
    global $G_CurrentTime;
    
    $TimeAgoString = '';
    $DateObject = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $RawDate));
    $DateDiff = $G_CurrentTime->diff($DateObject);
    $TimeAgoArray = (array)$DateDiff;
    print_r($G_CurrentTime);
    print_r($DateObject);
    print_r($TimeAgoArray);
    // years
    if ($TimeAgoArray['y'] > 0) {
        $YearString = 'year';
        if ($TimeAgoArray['y'] > 1) {
            $YearString .= 's';
        }
        $TimeAgoString = $TimeAgoArray['y'] . ' ' . $YearString . ' ago';
    }
    // months
    else if ($TimeAgoArray['m'] > 0) {
        $MonthString = 'month';
        if ($TimeAgoArray['m'] > 1) {
            $MonthString .= 's';
        }
        $TimeAgoString = $TimeAgoArray['m'] . ' ' . $MonthString . ' ago';
    }
    // days
    else if ($TimeAgoArray['d'] > 0) {
        $DayString = 'day';
        if ($TimeAgoArray['d'] > 1) {
            $DayString .= 's';
        }
        $TimeAgoString = $TimeAgoArray['d'] . ' ' . $DayString . ' ago';
    }
    // hours
    else if ($TimeAgoArray['h'] > 0) {
        $HourString = 'hour';
        if ($TimeAgoArray['h'] > 1) {
            $HourString .= 's';
        }
        $TimeAgoString = $TimeAgoArray['h'] . ' ' . $HourString . ' ago';
    }
    // minutes
    else if ($TimeAgoArray['i'] > 0) {
        $MinuteString = 'minute';
        if ($TimeAgoArray['i'] > 1) {
            $MinuteString .= 's';
        }
        $TimeAgoString = $TimeAgoArray['i'] . ' ' . $MinuteString . ' ago';
    }
    // seconds
    else if ($TimeAgoArray['s'] > 0) {
        $SecondString = 'second';
        if ($TimeAgoArray['s'] > 1) {
            $SecondString .= 's';
        }
        $TimeAgoString = $TimeAgoArray['s'] . ' ' . $SecondString . ' ago';
    }
    // just now
    else {
        $TimeAgoString = 'just now';
    }
    
    return $TimeAgoString;
    
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the expected result here, what are you getting instead?

Comment: `"Y-m-d h:i:s"` should probably be `"Y-m-d H:i:s"`. A lowercase `h` means 12-hour time.

Comment: i said in my post, expected result is that it will show "x hours ago" shortly after something is submitted, but instead it will show "1 day ago" when it hasnt been a whole day.  then it will revert back to "x hours ago". its weird and intermittent not sure why it is happening

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol wow i didnt notice that i will try that out!